# .Net Google Drive API - The Given Header was not found

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

This is more of an FYI about a bug in the .Net Google Drive v2 library.

When using:

`service.Files.Insert(body, Stream, mimeType)`

Make sure that the Stream position is at 0. Otherwise you will receive the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The given header was not found.
```

After writing some code to compare streams I struggled with this error for 2 days before figuring it out.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that with us! I created a new issue in our issue tracker for that - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=477. Feel free to add more data to it.